# Perlin worm between two specific points 3D. Or how to generate a tunnel between two points

Tags: java, 3d, procedural-generation, perlin-noise

My question title may seem like a XY problem, so let me explain it.
I am making a game that requires a cave group (Some caves that are connected with tunnels).
For now I have caves that are generated by a sphere with perlin noise offsets, so it is something like amoeba. Now I should connect these caves with tunnels.
My game uses the same technology as a Minecraft, so the map is generated as a 3d array of blocks.

So I have two caves and want to *connect them with random tunnel* (Build tunnel between two points). Maybe you can suggest something else than Perlin noise, maybe something like Bezier curves. The tunnel must have a thickness. ***Make something like Perlin worm between two specific points 3D***

Language: Java, but it does not matter, because this is a math task

There is more problems, for example tunnels should be something like air tubes covered with material like stone and then all this should be covered with material that players cannot break (Barrier, like minecraft's bedrock). Now my caves are covered with this barrier too, so I should somehow connect tunnel with cave to avoid ledges of barrier, but I think that I will do something around it. Now the main problem is random tunnel with two points

Thank you

Comment: You need to show what code you have attempted, and what the problem is with it.  We are not a code writing service.

Comment: Well, I have no ideas for tunnels for now. I was planning to use vectors, but it is not exactly whan I want. I do not need code from you, give me an idea how to generate something like 3d perlin worm between two points

Answer (score 0):

If you find a curve that looks good to you, try to find its SDF (signed distance function) by taking the distance to the curve minus the radius of the tunnel. You can do a similar thing with the spherical ones by taking the distance to the center minus r+(a bit of noise distortion). The great thing with working with SDFs is that you can combine them by taking the minimum of the two. In your case you can compute for each block the SDF to all the tunnels and caves and then take the min(), if the result is negative, the block should be air, otherwise, it should be stone.

To additional things you can do almost for free with this technique are :

1. you can say that if the result is between 0 and 1 block of distance, the block should be bedrock so the wall problem is solved.
2. you can use a [smoothmin](https://iquilezles.org/articles/smin/) function to get a nice transition between the caves and the tunnels.